# Stackdriver alert for % with label value?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a custom metric of type Count, which measures the count of a particular operation. It has a label called "success", which can be either "Success" or "Failure". I'd like to create an alert condition if the Failure % is above a certain threshold, perhaps 20%. Is that possible? If so, how would I do that? Or, do I need to change the metric itself to support this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can personalize your stackdriver alerting by targeting this labels with condition triggers where you will be able to set the percent of time series violates as you want 20%. You can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/ui-conditions-ga#title) guide to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I may need is to create a "metric ratio":

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-json#json-ratio

> With the API, you can create a policy that computes the ratio of two
>   related metrics and fires when that ratio crosses a threshold.

But somewhat unfortunately:

> Note: You can't create ratio-based policies through the UI.